# Jenkins Builds - PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, karma-runner

We have started seeing intermittent issues on our Jenkins build server when running jasmine unit tests with Karma.

We see the following error:

> PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL

This is usually goes away the next time we run the build, and we may not see the issue again for a couple of days.

We don't see this when running tests locally, so I'm wondering what could be different about our Jenkins environment that could cause this.

Can anyone offer any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: I am seeing this same error when I use FirefoxHeadless and instanbul for code coverage. If I just use ChromeHeadless or I don't use coverage, then this never happens. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution on that? I have the same problem...